# Firebase analytics monthly active users is larger than number of downloads

Tags: analytics, android, ios, firebase

We have an app for both Android and iOS that are tracked with Firebase Analytics. For both of these we get a higher active monthly users from Firebase Analytics compared to number of downloads of the app from Google Play developer console and iTunes Connect.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197564/firebase-analytics-incorrect-active-user-count) describes how reinstalls can skew the monthly active users count but I don't think that it explains the downloads/active users for a released app.

How can this be?
There must be something with how downloads and active users are counted that make phenomenon. Can it have something to do with multiple devices for one Google or Apple ID account?

Comment: Is the downloads number for all time?   If it is a monthly download number it could just be that users that installed in previous months are still using it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, your app is being downloaded from illegal apk sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

Google Play developer console and iTunes Connect counting active installs (**downloads - uninstalls**) but Firebase Analytics counts the number off active users in a month (**= downloads in this month + active users from last months**) regardless of uninstalls in this month.